# GROOVY RESTClient: No encoder found for request content type */*

Tags: java, api, rest, groovy

I am running a rest POST request and I am getting this error when I compile:

```
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No encoder found for request content type */*
```

Here is my code:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
def client = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost' )
def resp = client.post( path : '/services/adi/validateadimeta/fromfile',body : [ file:'foo' ] )
```

I am not sure if its responding or not maybe its a rencoding problem with the response? The `*/*` has me concerned that its not even making a connection. When I run this as a CURL command on the commandline it works fine.
`file` is the only parameter needed for this post call.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Accept` header?

Answer (score 8):

[Refer docs on `http-builder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient). Specifically,

> Since we never set a default content-type on the RESTClient instance
>   or pass a contentType argument in this request, RESTClient will put
>   Accept: / in the request header, and parse the response based on
>   whatever is given in the response content-type header.

Modify, `post()` call as below:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:'http-builder:0.7' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

def client = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost' )
def resp = client.post( 
    path: '/services/adi/validateadimeta/fromfile',
    body : [ file : 'foo' ],
    requestContentType : JSON 
)
```

Comment: I am posting this after some research; as i was having trouble specifying content type as 'JSON' i.e. all caps. My problem got resolved by changing 'requestContentType : JSON' to 'requestContentType : application/json'.

Comment: It is not a String. `JSON` refers to `groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON`. Please refer https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/ContentType.java#L58 @aamir

Answer (score 1):

When i add "**requestContentType : JSON**", it returned "**Bad request**"
It's changed to "**requestContentType: URLENC**", it works for me.

Read [documentation of RESTClient](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient) it explained for me

> Note that the above example is posting the request data as
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. (The twitter API doesn't support
>   XML or JSON POST requests.) For this reason, a requestContentType
>   parameter must be specified in order to identify how the request body
>   should be serialized.
>
> Since we never set a default content-type on the RESTClient instance
>   or pass a contentType argument in this request, RESTClient will put
>   Accept: */* in the request header, and parse the response based on
>   whatever is given in the response content-type header. So because
>   Twitter correctly identifies its response as application/json, it will
>   automatically be parsed by the default JSON parser.