# Groovy RestClient not using correct response handler for Content-Type: application/json?

Tags: rest, http, groovy, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm using Groovy's [RestClient.java](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/855e1784be8585de81cc3c99fd19285798c7bc4f/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.java) to POST some plain text to a server, the response I get back is JSON but I'm having some issues figuring out why the response is being parsed into a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) object instead of a [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) object.

From what I understand the response body should be parsed into an object based on the content type in the response header, the response header I get back is `application/json` but it seems like the it's defaulting to and parsing the response into a `StringReader` object. I'm not sure if I'm defining my headers incorrectly or whether I need to specify my own success handler?? I have other methods that use the POST method and work fine, however they are posting XML and expecting XML in response so I think the headers work out fine in that instance.

Below is how I'm attempting it and my logs, as you can see the response headers `Content-Type` is `application/json` so I'm baffled as to why `restClientResponse.getData()` is a `StringReader` object instead of a `JsonSlurper` object

```
def restClient = new RESTClient("http://this.doesnt.matter", 'text/plain')

restClient.setProxy("someproxy", 8080, "http")
restClient.setHeaders(Accept: "application/json")

def restClientResponse = restClient.post(body: "requestPayload:ACCOUNTPROFILE")
log.info(restClientResponse.getData())
log.info("What is in StringReader")

//Printing out what is in StringReader Object
def reader = restClientResponse.getData()
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
char[] characters = new char[1000]
builder.append(characters, 0, reader.read(characters, 0, characters.length))
log.info(builder.toString())

// Printing out each header in the response
restClientResponse.getAllHeaders().each {
    log.info("HEADER: " + it.getName() + ":" + it.getValue())
}

return restClientResponse.getData()
```

Logs:

```
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,561 uui.RestService java.io.StringReader@2a2e625
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,562 uui.RestService What is in StringReader
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,568 uui.RestService {"rbscResponse":{"errorMessage":"Unexpectederror","INSTALLATIONNUMBER":"","PRODUCTCOMMONNAME":"","errorCode":"30003","BTWSID":"","SERVICELINETYPE":"","CUSTOMERTYPE":"","RBSID":""}}
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,590 uui.RestService HEADER: Date:Tue, 14 Apr 2015 16:28:20 GMT
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,591 uui.RestService HEADER: Content-Type:application/json
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,591 uui.RestService HEADER: X-Powered-By:Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,591 uui.RestService HEADER: X-Cache:MISS from someproxy
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,592 uui.RestService HEADER: X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from someproxy:8080
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,592 uui.RestService HEADER: Via:1.0 someproxy (squid/3.1.10)
14 Apr 2015 17:25:04,593 uui.RestService HEADER: Connection:close
```

Any ideas as to why the response body isn't being parsed into a `JsonSlurper` Object?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570451/groovy-restclient-no-encoder-found-for-request-content-type. Try to set `requestContentType` as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove the Content-Type argument from the `RESTClient` constructor and specify the `requestContentType` in the post arguments like so:

```
def restClient = new RESTClient("http://this.doesnt.matter")
...
def restClientResponse = restClient.post(
    body:"requestPayload:ACCOUNTPROFILE",
    requestContentType: 'text/plain'
)
```

The problem was my (lack of) understanding as to what supplying the `RESTClient` constructor with a default Content-Type does. I assumed by supplying the `RESTClient` constructor with the Content-Type of `text/plain` it would set the Content-Type to `text/plain` in the **request header** then work out from the Content-Type in the **response header** which parser to use for the response body. However, I think by providing the RESTClient with an argument of `text/plain` that when it receives a response it ignores the Content-Type in the response headers and uses the Content-Type that was supplied in the RESTClient constructor.

Thanks to @dmahapatro for pointing me towards [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570451/groovy-restclient-no-encoder-found-for-request-content-type) question which lead me to read the [POST a status update to Twitter!](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient) section of the documentation